# using PositionPointer with MemoryMappedFile throw exception?

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

when i use PositionPointer with MemoryMappedFile i get error says

> Additional information: This operation is not supported for an UnmanagedMemoryStream created from a SafeBuffer.

, okay it is not supported but why c# developers put this property in MemoryMappedViewStream

this is my code :

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("hello.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        MemoryMappedFile mem = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fs,"map",0,
MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite,null,0,false);


        MemoryMappedViewStream mems = mem.CreateViewStream(0, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);

        unsafe
        {
            byte* pointer = mems.PositionPointer;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also run into this problem and I'm unsure why accessing `PositionPointer` throws on the `MemoryMappedViewStream` but if you use a `MemoryMappedViewAccessor` instead you will be able to attain a pointer.

```
using var file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew( "MyCustomFile", 1024, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite );
using var view = file.CreateViewAccessor( 0, 512, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite );            

// Attain a pointer to the unmanaged memory.
byte* ptr = null;
view.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer( ref ptr );

// You can store the pointer in a span for
// easy manipulation.
var span = new Span<byte>( ptr, 512 );
```