# How to get current read size when using Memory mapped file

Tags: c#, .net, performance, mmf

When reading a big size file using a Memory Mapped File, We have to wait until reading all data.
I hope to get the reading size when reading a big size file, Can I get the current read size information during the big size file reading?

Comment: Why can't you read the [Length of the FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.length?view=net-5.0) instance that belong to the file?

Comment: when reading a big size file like this: 
MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(path, FileMode.Open);
I have to read a 10GB file. When reading a file, I hope to show working status to user

Comment: You answer is as below:

1. Get the file size of the target
2. MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile() do
3. Another thread read the MMF file size and if it match, file is loaded

Is it right?

Comment: Yes, or do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59235387/578411

Comment: Ok I will try it